# add column with value depending on value in other column

Tags: r

Is there a smart way of doing this:

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

Now I want to add a column named X which could be either 1 or 0 depending on the name of the car. For example all cars starting with M should be 1 and the rest 0.

Best regards, 
H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this :

```
mtcars$X <- +(startsWith(rownames(mtcars), 'M'))
```

You can also use `grepl`/`str_detect` :

```
mtcars$X <- as.integer(grepl('^M', rownames(mtcars)))
mtcars$X <- as.integer(stringr::str_detect(rownames(mtcars), '^M'))
```

The above two are similar to using `ifelse` :

```
mtcars$X <- ifelse(grepl('^M', rownames(mtcars)), 1, 0)
```

but they are more efficient than using `ifelse`.

Comment: Just a following question. Now I want to adress the column mpg and when writing this:

mtcars$X <- -(startsWith(rownames(mtcars$mpg), 1))

Error in startsWith(rownames(mtcars$mpg), 1) : non-character object(s)

Eventhough i changed mpg to chr.

Comment: There is no `rownames` in `mtcars$mpg`. Try : `mtcars$X <- as.integer(startsWith(as.character(mtcars$mpg), '1'))`

Comment: One last question. Now I want to check my variable for multiple names(not just starting with 1 or M). I have made an array called TEST<-c("Mazda","Merc","Datsun") but when replacing with just TEST I wont get the correct result

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question instead of extending the question in comments. Anyway, in that case you can do `mtcars$X <- as.integer(grepl(paste0(TEST, collapse = "|"), rownames(mtcars)))`